# How to split number and character of string using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I would like to know how to split number and character into string in PHP.
for example.
I have string `B234CR45SV42` and I wan to split into

```
B 
234 
C 
R
45
SV
42
```

Please note that my code will change different character and numbers any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex in [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function to select target parts of string.

```
$str = "B234CR45SV42";
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]+|\d+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/d4ZQF)